# Si queréis contactar con los moderadores a través de flags, hacedlo en publicaciones (y no en comentarios)

Tags: soporte, faq, moderación, reportes

Cada mes los moderadores gestionamos entre 50 y 100 reportes (*flags*). Los hay de muchos tipos, pero básicamente se pueden dividir en dos:

- los que se hacen a comentarios.
- los que se hacen a publicaciones (preguntas o respuestas).

También podrían dividirse entre los que son manuales (un usuario los lanza) o automáticos (el [usuario Community](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) los lanza en base a distintos criterios). En [What is flagging?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) tenemos una descripción pormenorizada, muy completa y de fácil lectura. Os animo a echarle una ojeada y consultar aquí en Meta o [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46061) si tenéis alguna duda al respecto.

Lo que no queda claro en la descripción es qué ocurre con los flags y cómo os podemos contestar cuando los resolvemos. Pues bien, la cosa va así:

- Cuando un flag se pone en una publicación, podemos aceptarlo o rechazarlo. En ambos casos, podemos indicar un motivo, a elegir entre una lista de opciones enlatadas o incluso poner nuestro propio mensaje (cortito, como de 200 caracteres).
- Cuando un flag se pone a un comentario, solamente podemos aceptarlo o rechazarlo. Aceptarlo implica que el comentario se borre; rechazarlo, que el comentario permanezca. En ningún caso podemos poner mensaje alguno de respuesta.

Por tanto, **si con un flag buscáis algún tipo de interacción con los moderadores, ponedlo en una publicación**.

Comment: @walen si un moderador "soluciona" el flag (aceptándolo o rechazándolo), ese elemento sale de la cola de revisión. En el listado de flags nos aparece con un desfase de 30 minutos, pero luego "gana" allí donde se solucione antes. Por regla general, los moderadores decidimos levantar el pie del acelerador y tender a esperar a que sea la comunidad la que actúe, por lo que el caso que mencionas se solucionaría (como se solucionó) vía cola de revisión y votos de usuario no moderadores.

Comment: Ah, los flags caducan: si no se gestionan en un tiempo prudencial (creo que tres días), se marcan como _aged away_. Esto pasaba hace años por aquí. // Más info de todo esto en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291263/209901) a _What exactly does a VLQ flag do?_, donde explican también cuándo entra y cuándo no en la cola de revisión.

Comment: ¿puede haber un flag cuando sabemos que una respuesta es totalmente incorrecta o engañosa?, digo... para evitar la guerra de comentarios

Comment: @Mike si la cosa se acalora, sí, claro. Lee [What is flagging?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) y el resto de información interesante que aparece allí.